# Response time for a UIButton

Tags: iphone, uibutton, xamarin.ios, response-time

I have developed a test for iPod/iPhone (with MonoTouch if that is relevant) that measures reaction time. But I need to take into consideration the time between touching the screen and actual triggering of the button event. Is there any documentation of that?

Comment: Don't worry. It's not going to affect anything. Just make sure your code that registers the touch is efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already very hard to almost impossible to get predictable interrupt latency on real time operating systems.

But on the iPhone? Imho impossible. A capacitive touchscreen is not optimal to get results that are exactly the same for each body and location. And if mail.app decides to poll for emails just at the moment you'll touch the screen there will be a bigger delay.

But to make one thing clear, we are speaking about some micro seconds or even less than that.

If you want accurate results you shouldn't use an iPhone. But I guess your app will be some kind of game, so nobody cares if your result is 0.01 seconds off. But I wouldn't show results as 0.381829191 seconds, that fakes accuracy you'll never get on any smartphone.

What is the lowest reaction time you got in your app?

Answer (score 0):

The time between an actual touch and the system registering it will be negligable.

One key thing: if you are detecting the press using touch events like `touchUpInside`, consider using the `touchesDownInside` event because `touchesUpInside`, will not fire until the user's finger leaves the screen.

Comment: Fixed my answer by removing erroneous reference to UIButton.

Comment: Also, you down-voters could help more by actually leaving a comment too about why you down-voted.